# Deleting a node in a bst in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

```
void MorrisTraversal(tNode* root)
{
    tNode *current, *pre;
 
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
 
    current = root;
    while (current != NULL) 
 
        if (current->left == NULL) {
           
            current = current->right;
        }
        else {
             pre = current->left;
            while (pre->right != NULL
                   && pre->right != current)
                pre = pre->right;
            if (pre->right == NULL) {
                pre->right = current;
                current = current->left;
            }
            else {
                pre->right = NULL;
                current = current->right;
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I use this function to travers the bst, i also have a function (delete) that takes a node as parameter and delets it from the tree.
I'd like for example to remove from the tree all nodes whose value is 4, is it possible to do so using the functions mentioned above?
Like traversing the tree one time and removing all the nodes with a certain property.
I hope my problem it's clear...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add the definition of the tree nodes (tNode) for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will need to modify your Traversal function.

Currently `MorrisTraversal` traverses the tree, but it doesn't do anything to any node. You could modify `MorrisTraversal` to call a function on the current node (probably on the line after `while (current != NULL)`.

I would first try putting a simple print function/line there that prints the value of the current node and run it to verify your tree traversal works as expected.

Then you could change the print function to modify the node in some way.

If you do delete the node, you will have to be careful to clean up the tree. Eg. if you have the following tree Where A is the root node:

```
A-B-C
  |
  D-E
  |
  F
```

What happens if you delete `B`? Will you move `C`, `A`. or `D` into `B`'s place?

Good luck!